# How can I determine the latest Android version programmatically?

Tags: android, android-version

I want to check within my app whether the device runs the latest version of Android.

Is there a way to do that?

Yes, I could update my app once a year, but I would rather solve that problem technically.

Comment: The [minimum `targetSdkVersion`](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk) goes up every year, so you should be doing updates every year anyways.

Comment: Unless you want to create a webservice that publishes the version number of the latest Android and query it, no.  There's no way to no without a service publishing it what the latest Android is.  And even if you did, nobody ships stock Android-  they all cherry pick additions and all use different minor build releases.  So you could at most know if it was the right major version

Comment: Why do you even want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment from [Gabe Sechan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631193/gabe-sechan):

> Unless you want to create a webservice that publishes the version
>   number of the latest Android and query it, no. There's no way to no
>   without a service publishing it what the latest Android is. And even
>   if you did, nobody ships stock Android- they all cherry pick additions
>   and all use different minor build releases. So you could at most know
>   if it was the right major version

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this and check

```
String androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

And also following method will work

```
int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
String company = Build.MANUFACTURER;
String model = Build.MODEL;
String release = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

Log.e("TAG", "company " + company)
Log.e("TAG", "model " + model)
Log.e("TAG", "version " + version)
Log.e("TAG", "release " + release)
```

Comment: `Build.VERSION.RELEASE` I think this will just give current user version as string

Comment: how does it determine if you're running the latest version of Android or not?

Comment: it can be done by getting the version of the os by the above method and comparing it with the latest version

Comment: @Udara Abeythilake i understand that; but this code does only one part of the job. how do we obtain the latest Android version in code?